# Is there a keyboard shortcut to put the focus on the name box in Excel 2016?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2016

I wonder if I can jump to the name box (the one above the column "`A`", and below the ribbons) via a keyboard shortcut.
(somewhere I've read about <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, but it doesn't work)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't helpful but I can't find any such shortcut in the official list for Windows or MacOS. I can't test the MacOS but I don't think Command+F3 opening the "Define Name" dialog is what you want. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-in-excel-1798d9d5-842a-42b8-9c99-9b7213f0040f

Answer (score 3):

The keyboard shortcut to focus on the name box in Excel is
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.

Comment: Why the downvote? This was tested and worked.

Comment: +1: worked for me

Comment: In Excel 2016 it doesn't work. I've tested it on two different computers.

Comment: @Daniele: (Did you downvote?) There is no documentation on when this shortcut was introduced. If it doesn't exist for your version, you would need to create the shortcut, perhaps using AutoHotKey.

Comment: No, I did not downvote.

Comment: This shortcut not being available in your version means that your options are to either upgrade to a later version of Office, or to create the shortcut yourself.